# How to set a Bitmap Source to an image contained in a Viewbox?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, kinect

I have added code to get the video stream from a Kinect sensor and it works fine in one window with an image control.

But when I add the same implementation with a different xaml layout in a new window the feed doesn't show, so I'm guessing there is a problem with the way I have set up the xaml layout.

Does anyone know what could be causing the image to not show? 
Is there a property that is causing this or perhaps one that I'm not using?

This is how I have constructed the layout for the class in question:

```
<Window x:Class="BVversion1.ConditioningFrm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ConStackPanelditioningFrm"  Height="377.612" Width="637.313">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">   
             <Button x:Name="pushUpBtn" Content="Push Ups" Width="100" Click="pushUpBtn_Click"/>
             <Button x:Name="burpeeBtn" Content="Burpee" Width="100" Click="burpeeBtn_Click"/>
             <Button x:Name="squatBtn" Content="Squat" Width="100" Click="squatBtn_Click"/>
             <Button x:Name="coreBtn" Content="Core" Width="100" Click="coreBtn_Click"/>    
            </StackPanel>
            <Image x:Name="KinectVideo" Width="640" Height="250" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <Button x:Name="homeBtn" Content="Home" Width="75" Click="homeBtn_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

I set the image `KinectVideo` to the source of the bitmap like this:

```
KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel);
```

Comment: How do you bind ViewBox to the kinect camera?

Comment: I don't I just set image source aka "KinectVideo" to the BitMapSource...Should I be doing this differently if I'm using a viewbox?

Comment: Are you running both windows at the same time?

Comment: No,do you mean two video feed windows at the same time then no. The user will navigate to a game window, the video feed will start,a score counter will be displayed over the video and possibly an image,like a tree for example..

Comment: Hmmm... Also just a note, you should use a `WritableBitmap` as it is more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out in the end, all of the code was fine just that I have copy and pasted the event handlers for the video feed and page loaded which is why it wasn't being triggered.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?